# If a spell is cast on a wizard who then Apparates, will the spell survive?

Tags: harry-potter, apparition

Say a wizard performs a spell on himself, such as the Bubble-Head Charm or the Disillusionment Charm. Or another witch or wizard performs a spell on him. Will the effect of these charms not wear off after the wizard Apparates?

It is implicit in the question that these charms still have to be active when the wizard Apparates.

Comment: Well, Dumbledore Apparated while under the effect of the Ring curse. Is that something like what you mean?

Comment: No, like the disillusionment charm or the bubble-head charm.

Comment: So, specifically a spell cast *by* an individual themself?

Comment: Yes, that situation.

Comment: What an oddly specific question.

Comment: I'm not sure you've captured the essence of the question with your edit, @Valorum. If I understand it correctly, it's asking about the permanence of spells through Apparation. It's not implicit that said spells have to be concurrent with said Apparation. I.e. They don't have to happen simultaneously. That opens the question out a lot.

Comment: @TheDarkLord is right. What he said is what I was referring about when I opened the question.

Comment: In that case I've no idea what you're asking. VTC as "Unclear"

Comment: The wizard casts a spell on himself ( for example the bubble-head charm ). Will the spell survive after an Apparition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes. Spells are unaffected by Apparition.

Whilst he didn't perform the spell on himself, Ron did have his appearance altered magically before his trip to Gringotts.

> Hermione sighed and set to work, muttering under her breath as she transformed various aspects of Ron’s appearance. He was to be given a completely fake identity, and they were trusting to the malevolent aura cast by Bellatrix to protect him.
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26, Gringotts)*.</sub>

After he Apparates his disguise is still intact.

> Harry turned on the spot, with Griphook on his shoulders, concentrating with all his might on the Leaky Cauldron, the inn that was the entrance to Diagon Alley. The goblin clung even tighter as they moved into the compressing darkness, and seconds later Harry’s feet found pavement and he opened his eyes on Charing Cross Road.
>   [...]
>   Travers seemed a little taken aback at that, and he turned instead to Ron.
>   “Who is your friend? I do not recognize him.”
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26, Gringotts)*.</sub>

The most natural conclusion is that spells are unaffected by Apparition.

Comment: The OP is very specifically asking about spells cast on oneself. Not spells cast by other people

Comment: I think I mistakenly made my question too specific. The cast can be made by a wizard with his own hand/wand or by another wizard.